# How to set color variants for dark mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-color

I want need to design app for light and dark mode color palette. App is using 10 different colors for backgrounds/buttons/texts. What I want to achieve is set `theme` in `styles.xml` for dark mode and set darkMode variant for majority of those colors from opposite color spectrum. I have different shades of white and grey for texts/action bars. Problem is that I can set only 2 primary colors in my theme, `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark`. And these colors I never used in my app, because I have fully custom layouts with custom colors for each xml.

Is there any way how to achieve this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@vinitagrawal91/android-colors-and-multiple-themes-fdfca3f75a15

Comment: How to set these colors in code then? R.attr.customColorName doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can change those colors in colors.xml inside Values. Also you can declare the colors of your app there so you don't have to custom everything for each xml, you just have to add the name of the color that you previously declared.

Example:

**Colors.xml**

```
<color name="red">#f80404</color>
```

**In your view**

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="@color/red"/>
```